# Performing operations between two list of lists and keeping track of the initial list

Tags: python, list

I have something in mind that i find quite confusing to write. Pardon me for that and I'll jump into it right now.

Basically, i have **two list of lists**, each with different number of elements in them.

```
L1 = [[1.1,1.2],[1.3,1.4]]
L2 = [[2.1,2.2],[2.3,2.4],[2.5,2.6]]
```

Within my line of code, i have a **defined function** to find **'the shortest distance between two lists taken as a parameter'**. For example, in **L1**, the **first list** which is [1.1,1.2] is extracted and also in **L2**, the **first list** which is [2.1,2.2] is extracted. Then both this list goes through the function that returns the value. The process goes on such as [1.1,1.2] is then compared with [2.3,2.4] and so on until there is no more elements to compare. The values obtained from the function is then appended to a list as output where i get something like:

```
outputL = [values,values,values..... and so on as there are many combinations]
```

the problem I'm facing now is not being able to keep track of which list from L1 is paired with the ones in L2 while going through the function.

Example:

the first list in L1 obtained is [1.1,1.2] and L2 is [2.1,2.2] ==> goes through function ==> gets value ==> appended to list.

now instead of just many values all in a list, i would like to at least display the list element from L1 or L2 beside the value in the list so i will be able to keep track of which values belong to which list.

```
expected output would be something like : [values,1.1,1.2, values,1.3,1.4...so on]
```

I have a code:

```
outputL = []
for i in L1:
   for j in L2:
       results = shortest_distance(i,j) #shortest_distance is the defined function that takes two lists as it's parameter
       outputL.append(results)
print(outputL)
```

Comment: Looks like you are simply looking for `enumerate`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

This function will generate a list of all the possible combinations between the lists you provide it.

In your own 2 list example, this would be the result:

```
list( product( L1, L2 ) )
Out[56]: 
[([1.1, 1.2], [2.1, 2.2]),
 ([1.1, 1.2], [2.3, 2.4]),
 ([1.1, 1.2], [2.5, 2.6]),
 ([1.3, 1.4], [2.1, 2.2]),
 ([1.3, 1.4], [2.3, 2.4]),
 ([1.3, 1.4], [2.5, 2.6])]
```

You can then iterate over the combinations and run your distance function. In the example below I'm using euclidean distance since you haven't provided your own distance function, but you can of course replace `euclidean` with your own `shortest_distance`.

```
L1 = [[1.1,1.2],[1.3,1.4]]
L2 = [[2.1,2.2],[2.3,2.4],[2.5,2.6]]

from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean
from itertools import product

outputL = [ euclidean( a, b ) for pair in product( L1, L2 ) for a, b in pair ]
```